# Apt Dependency Problem: Packages in a PPA do not correctly depend on each other

Tags: 10.04, apt, ppa

I'm trying to install Wireshark 1.6 on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx from PPA (n-muench/programs-ppa2).
The `libwsutil1` version is named `1.6.0-1~ppa1` so it should satisfy `libwiretap1` dependency that needs version `1.6.0-1` ;
But it doesn't !!
I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install libwiretap1
```

And this:

```
sudo apt-get -fm install libwiretap1
```

Both responded this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libwiretap1: Depends: libwsutil1 (>= 1.6.0-1) but 1.6.0-1~ppa1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

(Notice that the `~ppa1` postfix seems to be the problem!)

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-1~ppa1` tells the system that this isnt `-1`, but rather a version that will be overridden by `-1`.  This therefore is not an issue with "version check", nor is it a mistake, it's by design.  The special `~` symbol in the version means "This version does not supercede version `-1` of the same package, and may be superceded by version `-1` of the package, or by a later upstream version release that gets packaged."

To do this, with the PPA, the version you see in that number would need to be `1.6.0-1` (within the PPA) in order for the system to recognize it as `1.6.0-1`.

This is why packages such as PHP 5 release candidates get overridden when a stable release comes out (`php 5.4.0-1~rc3` vs. `php 5.4.0-1`, where the rc3 is a release candidate and the non-rc3 is the stable)

Comment: But a problem: both `libwiretap1` and its dependency `libwsutil1` are from same PPA so both have "-1~ppa1" so they should work with eachother while they don't! it seems `libwiretap1` that has `-1~ppa1` itself, depends on pure `-1` verson of `libwsutil1`! Can I do something to fix this or I need find another PPA?

Comment: @4r1y4n that's because they didnt configure the packages correctly within the `debian/control` file of the PPA's packages. You'll need to either poke the creator of the PPA, and tell them to update both `debian/control` files' dependency lines to say: `[package] (>=1.6.0-1~ppa1)`, where `[package]` is the package name (whether its libwiretap1 or libwsutil1, such as in `libwiretap1`'s `debian/control`, `[package]` is `libwsutil1`), or find another PPA with correctly configured packages.

Comment: @4r1y4n (ran out of space)  Normally someone packaging programs would make sure the `debian/control` files wouldnt break like this, especially if they tack on the `~ppa#` suffix  (you should see my PPAs, if they depend on eachother as a version, they're set correctly before I upload to a PPA, but hey, i'm a packager, its a habit i check everything before making a PPA public, or "production stable" so to speak)